# How to reuse Mongoengine connection in python rq?

Tags: mongoengine, python-rq

I need to sync a lot of data on the back-ground using mongoengine through python rq and i would like to reuse connection. Syncing will be done all the time and i don't wanna open connection to mongo every time syncing process starts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoEngine internally keeps the Pymongo.MongoClient in a global dict in `mongoengine.connection`. You aren't supposed to interact with it, but if you need to, it is accessible with:

```py
from mongoengine import connect
from mongoengine.connection import _connections

connect()

print(_connections) # {'default': MongoClient(host=['localhost:27017'], document_class=dict, tz_aware=False, connect=True, read_preference=Primary())}
```

If you just want to use the MongoClient and issue pymongo queries, that's perfect but if you intend to use multiprocessing, make sure you read [this](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/faq.html#using-pymongo-with-multiprocessing), as the MongoClient is not fork-safe